# asp.net GridView and Checkboxes Dynamic Bind

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am having a little issue that I don't seem to understand the best way to approach.

I have a `GridView` that get automatic column generations based on the query I run. The `GridView` will contain (Name) (Description) (Edit) (Delete) (View) (Admin).

Now because the Edit, Delete, View... are bit's in the database when the query returns the results and binds the data with the `GridView` I get these grayed out `Checkboxes` with checked if True or Unchecked if False.

Now because I didn't create those disabled checkboxes are they really a `checkbox` or are the something that's just display like that... If they are really a `checkboxes` how do I access them and enable or disable them? I tried looping through each cell in grid but when I say cell.text it gives me empty string back... What would be the best way to approach this or am I misunderstanding the `DataBind` of a bit fields?

Thanks all for your help.

**UPDATED**

```
            string sSQLAccess = "SELECT ap.n_Name 'App', a.b_Edit 'Edit', a.b_Delete 'Delete', a.b_View 'View' " + Environment.NewLine
                + "FROM tbl_Actions a " + Environment.NewLine
                + "JOIN tbl_Applications ap ON ap.u_ID = a.u_ApplicationID" + Environment.NewLine
                + "JOIN tbl_Roles r ON r.u_ID = a.u_RoleID" + Environment.NewLine
                + "WHERE a.b_Deleted = 0" + Environment.NewLine
                + "AND ap.b_Deleted = 0 " + Environment.NewLine
                + "AND r.b_Deleted = 0 " + Environment.NewLine
                + "AND a.u_RoleID = '" + Request.QueryString["ID"] + "'" + Environment.NewLine;

            grdAccess.DataSource = vwAccess;
            grdAccess.DataBind();
```

Comment: 0
 
Could you show the code you used in your loop. Are you using a dataset at all?

Comment: check the **UPDATED** portion. vwAccess is a DataSet.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox will not be enabled unless the gridview is in edit mode - you would need to define an edit template for the gridview.